# Picom: Old backends only support blur method "kernel". Your blur setting will not be applied

Tags: linux, archlinux, i3

I wanted to know what i did wrong with my picom configuration file.
I'm currently using Arch Linux - 5.6.10 with i3-gaps as WM and Picom as a compositor.

**Error message:**

`[ 08/05/20 13:43:36.014 init_render WARN ] Old backends only support blur method "kernel". Your blur setting will not be applied`

Can someone please tell me what does that mean?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this error is probably because you have used ***gaussian*** blur or ***box*** blur in your picom config file. These are only supported by experimental backends as of now.

Use `picom --experimental-backends` to run picom and you should be able to get the blur effect. It is recommended you use `picom --experimental-backends --backend glx` as performance is better with glx.

Alternatively, you could use ***kernel*** blur. In that case, you should specify which kernel to use. Refer to the BLUR section of the man page of picom for more information.

Comment: what a brilliant solution my man! Thanks, `picom -b --experimental-backends --backend glx` works like a charm.